# Combining two tables

Tags: tabularx

How do I combine these two tables so there is no gap between the first and second table and connected with `\bottomrule`? I've tried to add both tables into one tabular environment but failed. Also why is group 7's column wider?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\keepXColumns
\setcellgapes{3pt}\makegapedcells
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{c|*{6}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}}%1.175
\toprule
\addlinespace
\captionsetup{textfont=it, skip=0.25ex}
    \caption{Number of dendrograms in each group for 1,000 Bootstrap samples}
    \label{table:KS_1k_groups}\\
    \midrule
                     & Group 1 & Group 2 & Group 3 & Group 4                             & Group 5 & Group 6\\
    \midrule
    \midrule
    Number of Dendrograms   & 13 & 12 & 5 & 4 (x3) & 3 (x4) & 2 (x4) \\
    Cophenetic correlation & - & - & - & - & - & \\          
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\keepXColumns
\setcellgapes{3pt}\makegapedcells
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{c*{7}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}}%1.175
    \midrule
                     Group 7 & Group 8 & Group 9 & Group 10 &                            Group 11 & Group 12 & Group 13 & Group 14\\
    \midrule
    \midrule
        - & - & - & - & - & - & - & -\\
        - & - & - & - & - & - & - & -\\          
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

The first table has 7 columns while the second has 8 columns. Trying to merge them together and hoping to get the same output can be complicated. It is best to keep the two tables separated but getting the second one closer to the first. Remove `\cmidrule` at the beginning of the second table and insert `\vspace{-1.5\baselineskip}` right after the first table. That way, your two tables would look as if they were only one table. Note that `float` package will also treat them as one table since they are both contained in the same table environment. Hence, the two tables will never be separated from each other no matter what your text is.

Group's 7 column is wider because the type is `c` not `X`

**Related:** instead of typing `>{ \arraybackslash \Centering }X` over and over in `tabularx` preamble, define `\newcolumntype{C}{ >{\arraybackslash \Centering}X }`. Now you can use `C` to refer to `X` column with centered content.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{ >{ \arraybackslash \Centering } X }
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{ltablex}

\begin{document}

\keepXColumns
\setcellgapes{3pt}\makegapedcells
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{c|*{6}C}%1.175
    \toprule
    \addlinespace
    \captionsetup{textfont=it, skip=0.25ex}
    \caption{Number of dendrograms in each group for 1,000 Bootstrap samples}
\label{table:KS_1k_groups}
\\
\midrule
     & Group 1 & Group 2 & Group 3 & Group 4 & Group 5 & Group 6
\\
\midrule
\midrule
    Number of Dendrograms   & 13 & 12 & 5 & 4 (x3) & 3 (x4) & 2 (x4)
\\
    Cophenetic correlation & - & - & - & - & - &
\\          
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\vspace{-1.5\baselineskip}

\keepXColumns
\setcellgapes{3pt}\makegapedcells
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{*{8}C}%1.175
    Group 7 & Group 8 & Group 9 & Group 10 &                            Group 11 & Group 12 & Group 13 & Group 14
\\
\midrule
\midrule
    - & - & - & - & - & - & - & -
\\
    - & - & - & - & - & - & - & -
\\          
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```